# generate excel file from stored procedure without creating directory in oracle

Tags: excel, oracle, stored-procedures, directory

I have below code which generates excel file. I have tested its wokring in my local machine and i have also create directory in oracle in my loacl machine database.

But now as i need to use this procedure in production where due to security reason i cannot create oracle directory then in this case the procedure is throwing error as

```
ORA-29280: invalid directory p
```

Is there any other way i can generate file in specific folder without creating directory in oracle ?

```
  Create or replace PROCEDURE test_report IS    
     lv_dir         VARCHAR2(4000);    
     lv_data_file   VARCHAR2(4000) := 'test_report' || '_' ||    
                                     to_char(SYSDATE, 'dd-Mon-yyyy') ||    
                                     '.csv';    
     lv_err_file    VARCHAR2(4000) := 'test_report' || '_' ||    
                                     to_char(SYSDATE, 'dd-Mon-yyyy') ||    
                                     '.csv';    
     lv_dfile       utl_file.file_type;    
     lv_efile       utl_file.file_type;    
     ln_err_cnt     NUMBER;    
     ln_prc_cnt     NUMBER;        

 BEGIN      

     lv_dir := 'C:\test\TEST_REPORT';    
     lv_dfile := utl_file.fopen(lv_dir, lv_data_file, 'W');    
     utl_file.fclose(lv_dfile);    
     utl_file.fclose(lv_efile);    



    EXCEPTION    
         WHEN OTHERS THEN    
          dbms_output.put_line(substr(sqlerrm,1,30));    
       END test_report;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple Answer: **No**.

In order to access the file system with your Oracle Database, Oracle provides the `DIRECTORY`s. This way, Oracle also keeps itself and all file-accessing-functions independent from the operating system.

There may be workarounds. `Oracle APEX` for example provides methods to enable an end-user to download a `BLOB` as a file from his web-browser which has been generated in the database. Using `XDB`, it could also be possible to store files in a directory-like system within the database. But, as far as I know, this does not use the physical hard drive.

You could write some lines of Java and compile it within the database, but not having worked with Java inside an Oracle Database, I assume that in order to access the file system, you would also need to use the Oracle Directories.